# Positive and negative voltage readings of chemical cells

Tags: redox

In the experiment of chemical cells, I connected a magnesium electrode , a copper electrode and a multimeter in a complete circuit.

When magnesium electrode is connected to the negative terminal and the copper electrode is connected to positive terminal, the reading of the multimeter is positive.

However, when copper is connected to the negative electrode and magnesium is connected to the positive electrode, the reading is negative instead.

I wonder what “positive” and “negative” reading means. Is it just defined by scientists that a positive voltage reading mean a flow of electrons from negative electrode to positive electrode, or can it be explained with scientific knowledge?

Answer (score 3):

One fundamental concept which is not taught clearly in electrochemistry is that the electrostatic sign of the electrode is invariant. Imagine you had a charge "sniffer" or charge sensor device, and if you were to touch a particular electrode in a electrochemical cell, you will always see the same electrostatic sign of the single electrodes, either positive or negative with respect to earth (UK, South/Asia) or ground (US). Imagine the only two possible scenarios- the electrode has excess of electrons then it has a negative electrostatic sign. If the electrode has a deficiency of electrons, it has a positive electrostatic sign. It will not matter, what you do. This is Nature's set-up.

Now when you are measuring the voltage using a multimeter, this time you are measuring *potential differences*,  and these differences are *directional* not in the sense of a conventional vectors/scalars, but the way meter is supposed to read the voltages. Imagine the old style galvanometers, where one could actually see the coils. The coils were wound in a certain direction and energized as such so that if the plus sign was connected to the plus sign of the direct current source the needle would deflect in a positive direction. If you swapped the connections, the needle moved in the opposite direction. This is what your multimeter is showing, but alas one cannot see anything in these modern black boxes. In one set-up, you see negative potential difference and in the other set up you see positive potential differences. The magnitude must be the same.

Comment: Hello AChem. I have always found very troublesome the concept of an "excess" or a "deficiency" of electrons in an electrochemical cell. The moment there is a reduction in the positive electrode, it will travel to the negative electrode and a compound will get oxidized. I think this accumulation or the opposite doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you mind if we discuss this thing in chat? It would be nice if I could clarify some points within this seemingly simple thing, and see if you think the same as me.

Comment: @MetalStorm, No the electrodes are indeed electrostatically charged (you really do not need many electrons) as long as the cell is alive. I do not know how to initiate a chat. Alternatively, you can compose a question.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this has very little/nothing to do with conventions of chemistry.

The same would happen if you measured potential differences between two points of electronic circuits, powered by a DC source plugged in the wall AC socket.

If you attached the positive voltmeter pin to more positive circuit potential and the negative/ground pin to more negative potential, you would read positive DC voltage. And vice versa.

For more, see the  term [electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential) on Wikipedia.

> ... is defined as the amount of work energy needed to move a unit of electric charge from a reference point to the specific point in an electric field. More precisely, it is the energy per unit charge for a test charge that is so small that the disturbance of the field under consideration is negligible.

In early years, before an electron was discovered, there was conventionally decided what is positive, what is negative and that a  current flows from conventional positive to negative potential. When an electron had been discovered, it was realized it had negative charge and its flow had the opposite direction than the conventional current. But the convention is kept since then.